# (MatchError) no match of right hand side value in cond statement

Tags: elixir

I have a function with the following:

```
cond do
  Enum.all?([10,11,12,13,1], fn x -> x in list end) == true -> { 9, [10,11,12,13,1] }
  Enum.all?([23,24,25,26,14], fn x -> x in list end) == true -> { 9, [23,24,25,26,14] }
  Enum.all?([36,37,38,39,27], fn x -> x in list end) == true -> { 9, [36,37,38,39,27] }
  Enum.all?([49,50,51,52,40], fn x -> x in list end) == true -> { 9, [49,50,51,52,40] }
  true -> { -1, [] }
end
```

For the catch-all, I'm getting `(MatchError) no match of right hand side value: {-1, []}`.

I feel like it's something simple but not really sure what I'm missing here. Appreciate any help!

Comment: The error is outside of the codepiece you’ve shared :) Please show how do you use what comes out. _Sidenote:_ `== true` is a noop and might be omitted inside `cond/1`.

Comment: @AlekseiMatiushkin Thanks for the advice. I ended up finding a solution based on your suggestion.

Comment: @jjkl, but put the answer here to others...